# FreeLookCam script with a different "world up"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to adjust the FreeLookCam script from the Standard Assets to work with my game, which has a different "world up" than standard unity projects. In my case, world up is -z, and I cannot seem to be able to adjust the script to fit this scenario.

Here is what it look like when I try it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ppb-tXvLZpI

and here is the code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
//using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Cameras
{
    public class FreeLookCam : PivotBasedCameraRig
    {
        // This script is designed to be placed on the root object of a camera rig,
        // comprising 3 gameobjects, each parented to the next:

        //  Camera Rig
        //      Pivot
        //          Camera

        [SerializeField] private float m_MoveSpeed = 1f;                      // How fast the rig will move to keep up with the target's position.
        [Range(0f, 10f)] [SerializeField] private float m_TurnSpeed = 1.5f;   // How fast the rig will rotate from user input.
        [SerializeField] private float m_TurnSmoothing = 0.0f;                // How much smoothing to apply to the turn input, to reduce mouse-turn jerkiness
        [SerializeField] private float m_TiltMax = 75f;                       // The maximum value of the x axis rotation of the pivot.
        [SerializeField] private float m_TiltMin = 45f;                       // The minimum value of the x axis rotation of the pivot.
        [SerializeField] private bool m_LockCursor = false;                   // Whether the cursor should be hidden and locked.
        [SerializeField] private bool m_VerticalAutoReturn = false;           // set wether or not the vertical axis should auto return

        private float m_LookAngle;                    // The rig's y axis rotation.
        private float m_TiltAngle;                    // The pivot's x axis rotation.
        private const float k_LookDistance = 100f;    // How far in front of the pivot the character's look target is.
        private Vector3 m_PivotEulers;
        private Quaternion m_PivotTargetRot;
        private Quaternion m_TransformTargetRot;

        protected override void Awake()
        {
            base.Awake();
            // Lock or unlock the cursor.
            Cursor.lockState = m_LockCursor ? CursorLockMode.Locked : CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = !m_LockCursor;
            m_PivotEulers = m_Pivot.rotation.eulerAngles;

            m_PivotTargetRot = m_Pivot.transform.localRotation;
            m_TransformTargetRot = transform.localRotation;
        }


        protected void Update()
        {
            HandleRotationMovement();
            if (m_LockCursor && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                Cursor.lockState = m_LockCursor ? CursorLockMode.Locked : CursorLockMode.None;
                Cursor.visible = !m_LockCursor;
            }
        }


        private void OnDisable()
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }


        protected override void FollowTarget(float deltaTime)
        {
            if (m_Target == null) return;
            // Move the rig towards target position.
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, m_Target.position, deltaTime*m_MoveSpeed);
        }


        private void HandleRotationMovement()
        {
            if(Time.timeScale < float.Epsilon)
            return;

            // Read the user input
//            var x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Mouse X");
//            var y = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
            var x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            var y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

            // Adjust the look angle by an amount proportional to the turn speed and horizontal input.
            m_LookAngle += x*m_TurnSpeed;

            // Rotate the rig (the root object) around Y axis only:
            m_TransformTargetRot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, m_LookAngle, 0f);

            if (m_VerticalAutoReturn)
            {
                // For tilt input, we need to behave differently depending on whether we're using mouse or touch input:
                // on mobile, vertical input is directly mapped to tilt value, so it springs back automatically when the look input is released
                // we have to test whether above or below zero because we want to auto-return to zero even if min and max are not symmetrical.
                m_TiltAngle = y > 0 ? Mathf.Lerp(0, -m_TiltMin, y) : Mathf.Lerp(0, m_TiltMax, -y);
            }
            else
            {
                // on platforms with a mouse, we adjust the current angle based on Y mouse input and turn speed
                m_TiltAngle -= y*m_TurnSpeed;
                // and make sure the new value is within the tilt range
                m_TiltAngle = Mathf.Clamp(m_TiltAngle, -m_TiltMin, m_TiltMax);
            }

            // Tilt input around X is applied to the pivot (the child of this object)
//            m_PivotTargetRot = Quaternion.Euler(m_TiltAngle, m_PivotEulers.y , m_PivotEulers.z);
            m_PivotTargetRot = Quaternion.Euler(m_TiltAngle, m_PivotEulers.y , m_PivotEulers.z);


            if (m_TurnSmoothing > 0)
            {
                m_Pivot.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(m_Pivot.localRotation, m_PivotTargetRot, m_TurnSmoothing * Time.deltaTime);
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, m_TransformTargetRot, m_TurnSmoothing * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                m_Pivot.localRotation = m_PivotTargetRot;
                transform.localRotation = m_TransformTargetRot;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related your question, but not using world up will reflect on other issues than just your camera adaptations script.

Rigidbody and particles gravity will have to be manually applied (which is just additional work, not unsolvable) and particle billboards will rotate in an undesirable way.

Answer (score 0):

There are two lines you need to change, both in HandleRotationMovement, and they both have to do with swapping the angles for y and z. The first one is on line 83:

```
// Rotate the rig (the root object) around Y axis only:
m_TransformTargetRot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, m_LookAngle);
```

and the second one is on line 101:

```
// Tilt input around X is applied to the pivot (the child of this object)
m_PivotTargetRot = Quaternion.Euler(m_TiltAngle + 90, m_PivotEulers.z , m_PivotEulers.y);
```

On that second line I had to add 90 degrees to get the tilt limits in the expected range in addition to swapping the y and z angles.